# Expert css selector please inside

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I need to create a multi-dimensional drop-down menu. But my hover selection don't work. I don't know how to use selector from other class div parent to other class div parent. Look at the code in style. i want to set rvcontainer to display block when hover to lvcontainer. Javascript solution is welcome

```css
        body {
          margin: auto;
        }
        
        #container {
          display: table;
        }
        
        #lcontainer {
          padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
          display: table-cell;
        }
        
        #rcontainer {
          padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
          display: table-cell;
        }
        
        .rvcontainer {
          display: none;
        }
    
        #lcontainer ~ .lvcontainer:hover + #rcontainer ~ .rvcontainer {
          display: block;
        }
```

```html
    <div id="container">
      <div id="lcontainer">
        <div class="lvcontainer">
          Country
        </div>
        <div class="lvcontainer">
          Genre
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="rcontainer">
        <div class="rvcontainer">
          Japan
          <br> Korea
          <br> American
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="rvcontainer">
          Comedy
          <br> Mystery
          <br> Horror
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a useful diagnostic. What is this supposed to do and what do you think has gone wrong?

Comment: @tadman I want when hover to lvcontainer. Rvcontainer will set to display block.

Comment: @daivdrush - while it is obvious from the data, it is not obvious from the markup which rvcontainer links to which lvcontainer. You need to have some sort of more obvious link between them - while you could go by index, it would probably be simpler and cleaner to just restructure your markup.

Comment: @potatopeelings from logic selector explain `#lcontainer > .lvcontainer:hover + #rcontainer > .rvcontainer {
      display: block;
    }` it should work right? using direct child selector to set hover and choose other child direct selector to set some value. but i likes miss something

Comment: It won't work because `.lvcontainer` and `#rcontainer` are not siblings.

Comment: Hi OP. I editted your post to embed - a nifty feature stackoverflow has. Makes answering your question a lot easier.

Comment: @Ravan but in front `.lvcontainer` i put the parent like `#lcontainer > .lvcontainer`.

Comment: CSS only digs deep, like it doesn't come out...
Here's what you're saying... Hey, select the `#lcontainer` and then select its direct child `.lvcontainer` and then select its (lvcontainer's) sibling `#rcontainer` [thats when it fails]. You just keep going deep into your selections and CSS completely forgets about what came before that.

Comment: @Ravan: CSS doesn't forget. It *remembers* that it's still in the context of .lvcontainer:hover. If it forgot, it probably would have been able to reach #rcontainer.

Comment: @BoltCheck Well yeah, but my point was that it doesn't come out.

Comment: why you are having child menu in separated div? why not inside parent menu? then it will be easier.

Comment: its just text block, how we will create dropdown out of it.  btw see how I put the child menu inside main menu, and use the hover. https://jsfiddle.net/stdeepak22/a4chgL33/6/

Answer (score 0):

First of all your CSS selector is wrong. It doesn't even select the element that's being hovered properly. It tries to select it as a sibling instead of as a child.

Second, this probably isn't possible with pure CSS. Because to achieve this, you would have to select the parent of the element and then the sibling of that parent.

**JAVASCRIPT:** You'll have to listen for the 'mouseover' event on the `.lvcontainer` and then change the display of `.rvcontainer` to block. And then on mouseleave event, set it back to whatever it was before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap to achieve this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Multi-Level Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>In this example, we have created a .dropdown-submenu class for multi-level dropdowns (see style section above).</p>
  <p>Note that we have added jQuery to open the multi-level dropdown on click (see script section below).</p>                                        
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

An example is from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h)